# Perform time consuming tasks inside UITableViewCell, pausing on scrolling

Tags: swift, uitableview, asynchronous, prefetch

I have TableView with customs cell representing events. It looks very close to first and third image here.

[image]

As you can see (sorry for small resolution) on some events there are photos of friends that are going to participate.
Unfortunately information about friends is not loaded with other information about events.

So after I got list of events I can make request to load list of friends that are going to participate in each event.

Right now I use code like

```
class EventCell : UITableViewCell {
  var eventForCell : Event? {
      didSet {
          eventTitleLabel.text = eventForCell.title
          eventDateLabel.text = eventForCell.date
          presentFriends(eventID : eventForCell.id)
      }
   }

   func presentFriends(eventID : Int) {
        //searching for friends for event with specific eventID
        .......
        .......

        //for every friend found adding UIImageView in cell
        for friend in friendsOnEvent {
          let avatar = UIImageView(....)
          self.addSubview(avatar)
        }
   }
}
```

This code works but photos are not presented in smooth way. Also if you scroll list fast they start to blink. Maybe it is even not necessary to load them if user scrolls fast list of events. So I have two questions:

1. How can I make smooth scrolling experience taking in consideration that presenting friends for every event can take time and sometimes it finishes after cell was scrolled away.
2. If I had loaded list of events and already presenting cells with them. How can I update those cells after I get information about friends that are going to participate?
3. When user is scrolling and I am creating async tasks to display some images in cell I think I should use weak reference to self and maybe check it not to equal nil so task would be canceled if cell is not visible now. How should it be done?

**Update:**

I found info about **tableView(_:prefetchRowsAt:)** method inside UITableViewPrefetchingDataSource protocol, should I use it for this case? Maybe someone has some experience with it?

Comment: If I am not wrong, the images are appearing from internet. You can use SDWebImage or Kingfisher library to load images. They load images asynchronously. Also it's better if the images you are loading are thumbnail sized.

Comment: You are right, I am already using SDWebImage to present images. But they are still blinking if I scroll fast.

Comment: Are you using the SDWebImage image fetching in cellForRowAt. Because if you scroll, the cell is redrawn and SDWebImage might try to fetch it again. Even though the library caches the request, it might call for the image again if cache miss or expiration happens.

Comment: yes, I am using it inside cellForRowAt, where should I put it? Is there some way to cancel image loading for cell if it is not presented anymore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** (Re)creating a view objects during `cellForRowAt` is generally a bad practice. From the screenshot I assume that there is a limit to how many avatars are there on a single cell - I would recommend creating all the `UIImageView` objects in the cell initializer, and then in `presentFriends` just set images to them, and either hide the unused ones (`isHidden = true`) or set their alpha to 0 (of course, don't forget to unhide those that are used).

**2.** If you are using SDWebImage to load images, implement `prepareForReuse` and cancel current downloads to get a bit of performance boost during scrolling, and prevent undefined behaviour (when you try to set another image while the previous one was not yet downloaded). Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17222434/sdwebimage-cancel-download), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22914624/how-to-cancel-download-with-sdwebimagedownloader) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17073240/is-there-any-way-to-stop-an-image-in-a-uiimageview-from-lazy-loading-with-sdwebi) I would expect something like:

```
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
    
        self.imageView.sd_cancelCurrentImageLoad()
    }

 Or you can use [this gist][4] for an inspiration.
```

**P.S.:** Also, you will have to count with some blinking, since the images are downloaded from web - there will always be some delay. By caching you can get instantly those that were already downloaded, but new ones will have delay - there is no way to prevent that (unless you preload all the images that can appear in tableView before presenting tableView).

**P.S.2:** You can try to implement prefetching using `[UITableViewDataSourcePrefetching][6]`. This could help you out with blinking caused by downloading the avatars from web. This would make things a bit more complicated, but if you really want to remove that blinking you will have to get your hands dirty.

First of all, as you can see from the documentation, `prefetchRowsAt` does not give you a cell object - thus you will have to prefetch images to your model object instead of simply using `sd_setImage` on the `UIImageView` object at a given cell. Maybe the aforementioned [gist](https://gist.github.com/keighl/6319942) would help you out with downloading images to model.

Now also as the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasourceprefetching) states:

> **Loading Data Asynchronously**
>
> The `tableView(_:prefetchRowsAt:)` method is not necessarily called for every cell in the table view. Your implementation of `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` must therefore be able to cope with the following potential situations:
>
> Data has been loaded via the prefetch request, and is ready to be displayed.
>
> Data is currently being prefetched, but is not yet available.
>
> Data has not yet been requested.

Simply said, when you are in `cellForRowAt`, you cannot rely on `prefetchRowsAt` being called - it might have been called, and it might not have been called (or maybe the call is in progress).

Documentation continues to suggest using `Operation` as a backing tool for downloading the resources - `prefetchRowsAt` could create `Operation` objects that would be responsible for downloading avatars for a given row. `cellForRowAt` can then ask the model for the `Operation` objects for the given row - if there are not any, it means that `prefetchRowsAt` was not called for that row, and you have to create `Operation` objects at that point. Otherwise you can use the operations created by `prefetchRowsAt`.

Anyway, if you decide that it is worth it, you can use this [tutorial](https://andreygordeev.com/2017/02/20/uitableview-prefetching/) as an inspiration for implementing prefetching.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`UITableViewDataSourcePrefetching`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasourceprefetching) as you mentioned.

It's a protocol that calls your prefetch data source when some cells are going to be displayed but are not on the screen yet.
This way you can prepare all the resources that takes time to load before they are presented.

You just have to implement:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, prefetchRowsAt indexPaths: [IndexPath])
```

and fetch the data related to the cells from all of the `indexpaths`.

Beware it's only available since **iOS10**.

---

I personally use AlamofireImage with a cache so images that have already been downloaded aren't fetched twice, there's plenty of alternatives  but it's a good practice to use cached images on this kind of scenario.